# Was SE Meta the best place to post this, or would it have been better to post it here?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, meta

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271358/indicator-to-the-left-of-the-review-button-broken-or-hidden-meaning) on SE Meta.

Was that the best place, or would it have been better to post it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking there was the right place, I think.

It is probably not SR-specific.